# Calculate average of 1kb windows

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

My files looks like the following:

```
18  1600014 +   CAA 0   3
18  1600017 -   CTT 0   1
18  1600019 -   CTC 0   1
18  1600020 +   CAT 0   3
18  1600031 -   CAA 0   1
18  1600035 -   CAT 0   1
...
```

I am trying to calculate the average of column 6 in windows that cover 1000 range of column 2. So from 1600001-1601000, 1601001-1602000, etc. My values go from 1600000-1700000. Is there any way to do this is one step? My initial thought was to use `grep` to sort these values, but that would require many different commands. I am aware you can calculate the average with `awk` but can you reiterate over each window?

Desire output would be something like this:

```
1600001-1601000    3.215
1601001-1602000    3.141
1602001-1603000    3.542
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU awk to gather the counts and sums, if I understand your problem correct, you might need something like this:

```
BEGIN { mod = 1000 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
      }

    {
      k= ($2 - ( $2 % mod ) ) / mod
      sum[ k ]+= $6
      cnt[ k ]++
    }

END { 
      for( k in sum ) printf( "%d-%d\t%6.3f\n", k*mod +1, (k+1)*mod, sum[k] / cnt [k])
    }
```

Comment: Thank you works perfectly! Not sure why but the output is not in logical order so I just piped your command in to `sort` in order to regain numerical order

Comment: @RyanZapotocny Please have a look at the chapter Controlling scanning in the gawk docu: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html , you can add a `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` statement in the BEGIN section. I think that will take care of the sorting issue.